# KivyMD Update Label Text

Tags: python, datepicker, kivy, label

I´m trying to figure out, how to get the selected date from my Datepicker into a Label in the kv file. Maybe someone can help me. Greetings
The code from py file

```
from tkinter import Button
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.picker   import MDDatePicker
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class Demo(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("layout.kv")
        return Demo()
    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
        
        print(instance, value, date_range)
        fristbeginn = StringProperty(value)

    def on_cancel(self, instance, value):
        '''Events called when the "CANCEL" dialog box button is clicked.'''

    def show_date_picker(self):
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
        date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save, on_cancel=self.on_cancel)
        date_dialog.open()

#class DatePicker(Button):


   

class Content(BoxLayout):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()
    manager = ObjectProperty()
    



Main().run()
```

The code from .kv file:

```
<Content>:
  ScrollView:
       MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 1"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.manager.current = "screen1"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 2"   
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.manager.current = "screen2" 

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 3"   
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.manager.current = "screen3" 

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 4"   
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.manager.current = "screen4" 

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 5"   
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.manager.current = "screen5" 






<Demo>:
   Screen:
        adaptive_size: True
        MDToolbar:
            pos_hint: {"top":1}
            title: "Menü"
            elevation: 8
            left_action_items:[["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open") ]]
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            Content:
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
                manager: screen_manager
                

        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                Screen:
                    name: "screen1"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Guten Tag Bildschirm 1"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "screen2"
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        adaptive_size: True
                        size_hint: .8, None
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': .7, 'center_y': 0.55}
                        spacing: '20dp'
                        padding: ('20dp', '20dp', '20dp', '20dp')
                        
                        MDLabel:
                            text: "Berechnung einer Frist nach §183 BGB:"
                            halign: "left"
                            font_style: "Subtitle1"
                            #pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                        MDLabel:
                            text:""
                            halign: "center"
                        MDLabel:
                            text: "Wählen sie den Tag des Fristbeginn aus"
                            halign: "left"
                            font_style: "Subtitle2"

                        MDRaisedButton:
                            text: "Datum wählen"
                            
                            on_release:app.show_date_picker()
                        MDLabel:
                            id: fristbeginn
                            text: root.fristbeginn
                            halign: "left"
                            font_style: "Subtitle2"
                        MDRaisedButton:
                            text: "MDRaised Button"    
                        MDRaisedButton:
                            text: "MDRaised Button"
                        MDRaisedButton:
                            text: "MDRaised Button"
                        MDRaisedButton:
                            text: "MDRaised Button"
                        MDRaisedButton:
                            text: "MDRaised Button"


                Screen:
                    name: "screen3"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Guten Tag Bildschirm 3"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "screen4"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Guten Tag Bildschirm 4"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "screen5"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Guten Tag Bildschirm 5"
                        halign: "center"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Using a `StringProperty` is a good idea, but you must define a `StringProperty` inside a class, but not within a method. Since your `kv` references `root.fristbeginn`, that property must be in the `Demo` class, like this:

```
class Demo(ScreenManager):
    fristbeginn = StringProperty()
```

And the `on_save()` method becomes:

```
def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
    print(instance, value, date_range)
    # fristbeginn = StringProperty(value)
    self.root.fristbeginn = str(value)
```